# How to approach my boss about helping me fund further training/MBA?

Tags: education, training, certification

I work in a small-medium-sized business (150-200 people) which is doing incredibly well and I have been a sales manager for about 3 years here, gaining a lot of tenure and reputation as an instrumental part of building the company.

As you might guess from my other posts/questions here, currently I am not exactly in the best period of my role here due to multiple reasons (either the tasks assigned to me and/or my health issues). So I was thinking of a new option, maybe a way out, a fresh perspective, while staying loyal to the company: executive education.

This can be pretty expensive nowadays, e.g. an MBA, but there are also less expensive options like professional certifications.

How do you usually go about asking your boss for support in pursuing work-related studies - both financially and work-wise?

Since my company is quite young and small, there are no formal procedures for employee training yet, so I could be a pioneer (which will make it difficult).

Comment: Sure... but there might be others for whom this question is more relevant?
Also, at some point I will have to ask them, so I want to be prepared.

Comment: I think this question is good at core but right now is a bit much "what do you all think" instead of focusing a specific question.

Answer (score 4):

> How do you usually go about asking your boss for support in pursuing
>   work-related studies - both financially and work-wise?

It might be best to first resolve your issues of not understanding what you are being told, and not performing well when you have your allergies - before you ask for support from your boss.

If/when you are in good standing you just ask "Hey, boss - I'd like to further my education at night, obviously on my own time. Does the company offer tuition reimbursement or other help with expenses?"

Note: Don't try this until you are on good terms. This shouldn't be viewed as a "way out" - it isn't. It's a perk that some companies offer on a routine basis (but apparently would have to be specially granted at your company). If you are assisted in your education, it wouldn't likely change anything about your understanding of directions from your boss. And it clearly wouldn't change anything about your allergy issues. Nothing about this is a "way out".

Comment: It should be noted that many companies who will fund additional education in areas that benefit the business will explicitly **not** fund MBA courses. If you really see that as necessary your career path, you're expected to make the investment yourself. This is partly due to doubts about whether an MBA is as valuable as is claimed, and partly due to beliefs that if you aren't willing to spend your own money on (essentially) changing careers you aren't motivated enough to be worth supporting.

Comment: I have not either.  The reason of "an MBA might not be vauluable" is subjective and is a bad reason to not allow it which means its likely not an actual reason.  I have learned more about management and what makes a manager sucessful getting my MBA then I have in my entire career in my position.